# Exercise about weak topology

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $(E,||\cdot||)$ be a Banach space, $M\subset E$ a linear subspace and $f_0 \in E^*$. Prove that there exists $g_0 \in M^\perp$ such that
$$
\inf_{g \in M^\perp} ||f_0-g|| = ||f_0-g_0||
$$
HINT: Note that $B_{E^*}$ is compact for $\sigma(E^*, E)$ and $M^\perp$ is closed in $\sigma(E^*,E) $.

I tried following the hint and I showed that $M^\perp$ is closed, since 
$M^\perp= \bigcap_{x\in M} J_x^{-1}(\{0\})$ is an intersection of closed sets; I also know that $B_{E^*}$ is compact. Anyway, I do not know how to proceed (I thought of using sequential compactness of the closed unit ball in $E^*$, but it seems that the hypothesis that $E^*$ is separable is necessary to have it).
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Do you know that compactness implies the existence of a weak* convergent subnet?

Comment: Actually, I do not know what nets are...I'll read something about, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists a sequence $\{g_n\}\subset M^{\perp}$ such that $\|f_0-g_n\|$ converges to LHS. By compactness the sequence $\{g_n\}$ has a subnet $\{g_n'\}$ converging to some $g_0 \in M^{\perp}$. For any $x \in E$ we have $g_{n'}(x) \to g_0(x)$ and $|f_0(x)-g_{n'}(x)|\leq \|x\| \|f_0-g_{n'}\| \to $ (LHS) $\|x\|$. So $|f_0(x)-g_0(x)| \leq $ (LHS) $\|x\|$.  Taking sup over $x$ in the unit ball of $E$ we get RHS $\leq $ LHS. The reverse inequality is obvious.